# Service org.kde.ksmserver does not exist

Tags: kde, d-bus

I'm running a box that has an old version of KDE (3.5.7). I was looking at restarting the KDE session from the command line and reading online I found the following solution using `qdbus`:

`qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 0`

This works in my main machine with KDE 4.14.9, but on the older one the `org.kde.ksmserver` service does not exist. This is all that's available:

```
$ qdbus
:1.6
org.freedesktop.DBus
```

Is this because of the old version of KDE? Could this be the result of a stripped down configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently KDE only started using DBus after version 4. Prior versions used dcop, and there are equivalent ways of ending a dekstop session with it:

```
DISPLAY=:0 dcop ksmserver ksmserver logout 0 0 0
```